# Error on the new review page

Tags: bug, review

I just found this error on the review page:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for asking, but were's the error exactly?

Comment: I spotted it on the reviews page, while the current version was still in beta (see the URL in the screenshot), but it never happened afterwards, so whatever it was, I believe it was fixed.

Comment: Can we add the completed tag then?

Comment: I do believe so, yes.